# Airflow Tasks fail with Pool 1 and concurrency of 4

Tags: parallel-processing, airflow, pool

Appreciate help for anyone who can point us in the right direction.

We have an airflow pooling configuration where we have plan to limit concurrency on API calls on our mariaDB to 1 so that we don't overload the DB. 
Our main goal is to parallelism for tasks that don't require throttling so that we improve the speed of our Daily ETL.

For this we have set pool slots of replica_db to 1 as seen in the image below
[image]
In our dag diagram below we intend to set the first two tasks to use replica_db slot

```
# #=====================================
# # JOB TASKS
# #=====================================

for TBL in LIST_OF_TABLES:
    prepare_sql                         =       bash_templateV2('prepare_sql',TBL,'replica_db')
    extract_lalafood_prod_replica       =       bash_templateV2('extract_lalafood_prod_replica',TBL,'replica_db')
    load_to_s3                          =       bash_templateV2('load_to_s3',TBL,'default_pool')
    copy_to_dwh_staging                 =       bash_templateV2('copy_to_dwh_staging',TBL,'default_pool')
    insert_to_dwh_production            =       bash_templateV2('insert_to_dwh_production',TBL,'default_pool')
    delete_csv                          =       bash_templateV2('delete-csv',TBL,'default_pool')

    #=====================================
    # DEPENDENCY GRAPH
    #=====================================

    prepare_sql >> extract_lalafood_prod_replica >> load_to_s3  >> delete_csv >> copy_to_dwh_staging >> insert_to_dwh_production
```

and the DAG diagram looks like this. The sample below just shows 3 main tasks but its actually more than that as it represents one table that we're extracting from DB. 
[image]

When we start the automation we get an error stating that the task failed because there are no slots. We can't seem to figure this out.
[image]

Doesn't Airflow put the tasks to wait in queue ? why does it mark it as fail? Our assumption is that because we only set 1 slot airflow still tries to execute 4 tasks at a time because of our concurrency settings. How do we fix this issue such that the firs two tasks don't fail and wait in queue until a replica_db pool slot opens up before proceeding to the next task node?

Here's our dag settings

```
# These args will get passed on to each operator
# You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': STATIC_DATE,
#     'email_on_failure': True,
#     'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
    # 'wait_for_downstream': True,    
    # 'dag': dag,
    'sla': timedelta(hours=2),
    'execution_timeout': None,#timedelta(seconds=300),
#    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    # 'on_failure_callback': some_function,
    # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function,
    # 'on_retry_callback': another_function,
    # 'trigger_rule': u'all_success'
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = '{}__EngFlix__prod_replica_v2B__start_{}'.format(STAGE.upper(),STATIC_DATE.date()),
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Data stream service for prod preplica to redshift',
    schedule_interval=CRON_SCHEDULE,
    max_active_runs=1,
    concurrency=4
)

def bash_templateV2(STEP,TABLE_ID,POOL):
  return BashOperator(task_id="{}-{}".format(STEP,TABLE_ID),
                      bash_command=EXE_PATH+"{} {} {}".format(EXECUTION_TIME_PLACEHOLDER,STEP,TABLE_ID),
                      pool=POOL,
                      dag=dag
                      )
```